# Can snowalert detect the failure of a snowflake task?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to detect an error related to snowflake task execution.

Can snowalert be used to alert me when a task fails?

If possible, please tell me the specific method.
(How to query)

Comment: As far as I know, Snowalert cannot detect failures and send notifications but it needs to be informed that the task has failed. That way it sends out the alert.

Comment: Thank you for sharing useful information.
I appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 0):

**Snowalert** cannot detect failures on its own. It works by querying Snowflake data on a regular schedule.

See more information [here](https://snowalert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/about.html#how-it-works).

Comment: Thank you for sharing useful information.
I appreciate it very much.